# Installing openmpi onto OSX Yosemite using macports

Tags: macos, path, osx-yosemite, macports, openmpi

I'm currently trying to install openmpi onto my mac (OSX Yosemite) using Macports. I've tried this several times and each time the install seems to be successful, but it then doesn't seem to work when trying to use it. For example, entering *"ompi_info"* returns *"-bash: ompi_info: command not found"*. Reading around similar threads, it seems like there might already be some openmpi installed on a mac but without a fortran compiler, and so the openmpi I am trying to install is going into another place, which I need to add to the PATH. Is this right, or is something else the problem? And how do I solve it?

Thanks a lot for any help you are able to give!

Comment: just a comment: installing openmpi on a mac via source code compilation has been made pretty easy. basic `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install` combination is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Ports should take care of your paths, but you might still need to select it for your MPI. You might try something like this:

```
sudo port install openmpi-gcc5 +fortran
sudo port select gcc mp-gcc5
sudo port select mpi openmpi-gcc5-fortran
```